# Has 616 Spider-Man ever had a cape?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, costume

Today, Facebook unearthed a post my father made in 2009 that questioned why Spider-Man now had a cape. I messaged him to ask about it and he said that he couldn't remember what he was talking about.

I searched for images of Spider-Man with a cape and found a few official-looking images. However, none seem to be of the normal Spider-Man.

[image]
[image]

**Has Peter Parker, of the 616 Marvel Universe, ever had a cape on his Spider-Man costume?**

Comment: Do you have the image from your FB message?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your first image is from Spider-Man 2099. The second one (left side) is a variant cover (by Alex Ross) to Secret Wars -- and also a homage to the What If story at the right side of the pic.

That said, I remember [an episode](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1911491/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) from Ultimate Spider-Man (TV series, certainly not Earth 616) where he uses Doctor Strange's cloak for a while.

[image]

And here comes Spider-Thor from Earth 20051 :)

[image]

I was not able to find anything in the main continuity though.

Comment: I've tried to find something is this page [http://www.angelfire.com/myband/skacorps/chris/smen.html ], but I couldn't find any capes in the main continuity.

Answer (score 7):

Spider-Man did originally have some webbing in his underarm area, which provided some limited gliding abilities.

That’s not quite a cape, but maybe it’s what your dad had in mind?

[image]